# OpenCV cvFindContours questions

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, opencv, sudoku

I'm following this guide: http://www.aishack.in/2010/08/sudoku-grabber-with-opencv/2/
and modifying to iOS 5.0.

I managed to find the largest contour (the sudoku "board"), however, it only locates the surrounding square, without the lines inside, as in the tutorial. can this be easily solved?

I'll try and find a way around it, but still would like to know. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using the camera right now. Try to load the image what is used in the tutorial and check if your implementation works on that image. Then you can continue with nice sudoku images from the web. You may also change the camera angle and distance from the sudoku when taking pictures to get a better, clearer view.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, but I'm currently using the image from the tutorial, still no luck.

Comment: Then you can play with a simpler, hand drawn image of 9 rectangles and check if it is better with that.